# Why I can't obtain the entire list of my remote branches in GIT?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

I am not so into **GIT** and I have the following problem. I am using GIT on an Ubuntu machine. I also tried with a Mac machine and I am not obtaining the same problem

I created a new branch into my **BitBucket** project repository. This branch is named **feature/Tab-Generalization** and how you can see it exists into my repository

[image]

The problem is that I cant see it performing the command:

```
git branch -a
```

In fact I obtain this output:

```
developer@developer-virtual-machine:~/git/energy-prg-be$ git branch -a
  Energy-PRG-BE
* feature/Tab-Generalization
  master
  remotes/origin/master
```

I suppose that the selected **feature/Tab-Generalization** is the local branch because the remote one should start with "remote" (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion) and not my remote one.

Performing **git branch -r** to obtain the list of remote branches I obtain:

```
developer@developer-virtual-machine:~/git/energy-prg-be$ git branch -r
  origin/master
```

But I was able to push on this remote branch doing:

```
git push origin feature/Tab-Generalization
```

and in fact in my BitBucket I obtain:

[image]

So what is wrong? What am I missing? How can I obtain the entire list of my remote branches?

**EDIT-1:** This is the output of **git remote -v**::

```
developer@developer-virtual-machine:~/git/energy-prg-be$ git remote -v
origin  https://AndreaNobili@bitbucket.org/AndreaNobili/energy-prg-be.git (fetch)
origin  https://AndreaNobili@bitbucket.org/AndreaNobili/energy-prg-be.git (push)
```

Comment: Have you tried `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`? What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon yes I tried both (what is the difference between "git fetch" and "git fetch origin"? I put the outpuit of "git remote -v" at the end of my original post

Comment: Does `git remote update -p` help?

Comment: @0andriy no, same situation :-(

Comment: In your local repository, run `git config --get remote.origin.fetch` and tell us what that prints. My guess is it prints `+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` because you made your clone with `git clone --single-branch`. (The one run on your Mac will presumably show the default `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, as that clone was presumably *not* made with `--single-branch`.)

Answer (score -4):

You could try "git remote show origin"

This should list all the branches in the remote repo that "origin" points to.

One possible issue could be that the branch is not what they call a "tracking branch".
If it is a tracking branch, then git keeps track of the relationship between the remote branch and the local branch.
The first time you push a branch, it is common to push with the -u option.
This makes it a tracking branch. If you did that, then the output of the command "git remote show origin" will say "tracked" next to the branch name.

If it doesn't say tracked, do:
git branch -u origin/branch-name

e.g.

git branch -u origin/feature/Tab-Generalization

This will cause it to be tracked, and may fix your issues.